# Integrate tag filters into the Android App

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tag-filters

I use the stackexchange.com tag filters pretty often to keep track of multiple sites at once. It is much more convenient to see all new questions for my favorite sites in one list than having to open each site sequentially to see if anything new was posted.

It would be nice to have the tag filters available in the app. I don't think there is any need to be able to create or modify filters in the app, but viewing your existing filters would be useful.